# How to perform multidimensional scaling where a subset of points are already fixed?

Tags: r, multidimensional-scaling

I have two sets of psychological variables. For simplicity, there is set A (10 variables) and Set B (10 variables).

When you map Set A using two-dimensional multidimensional scaling (e.g., using `MASS::isoMDS` in R) you get a standard circular representation.
I would like to now do another multidimensional scaling using all 20 variables (i.e., combining Set A and Set B) but hold the points for Set A fixed. I.e., I want to see how Set B maps onto Set A, when the Set A coordinates are held constant.

Is there a function in R that performs multidimensional scaling where some of the objects can be assigned a pre-determined position and some are free to vary?

Comment: +1. I don't know the answer, but I am wondering what is  "a standard circular representation"?

Comment: Are you aiming to plot the variables or cases as the points of MDS?

Comment: @amoeba, I'm not sure what Jeromy calls `a standard circular representation`, but often MDS with too (for the diven data) low dimensions or inadequately chosen other MDS parameters produce a map with the points spread about in a circle-like shape. It is called "degenerated" configuration. Wonder if Jeromy meant this.

Comment: Not quite clear what exactly you mean by `pre-determined position` and `fixed`. Is that you know the coordinates before the space is constructed?

Comment: This sounds a bit like procrustes analysis. Search this site.